# How to check if multiple RequestParameters are given in Get Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In the Get request method given below I want to check if more than 1 parameters are given in the request.
It is only allowed to use one of the three possible parameters, when more than 1 is given I will throw an error.

```
@GetMapping()
    public List<Offer> getOffers(@RequestParam(required = false) String title,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String status,
                                 @RequestParam(required = false) Double bidValue) {
        if (title != null) {
            return offerRepo.findByQuery("Offer_find_by_title", title);
        }
        if (status != null) {
            if (EnumUtils.isValidEnum(Offer.Auctionstatus.class, status)) {
                return offerRepo.findByQuery("Offer_find_by_status", Offer.Auctionstatus.valueOf(status));
            }
            else{
                throw new
                        ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, String.format("Status=%s is not a valid auction status ", status));
            }
        }
        if (bidValue != null) {
            return offerRepo.findByQuery("Offer_find_by_minBidValue", bidValue);
        }

        return offerRepo.findAll();}
```

How can I check if more than 1 `RequestParam` is given in the request?

Comment: You can create a Request model with three fields title, status, bidValue and create custom Validator. It will be OOP solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to get request params as map and check the size of the map if it is bigger than 1 throw exception.

From `@RequestParam` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

> If the method parameter is Map<String, String> or MultiValueMap<String, String> and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

```
public List<Offer> getOffers(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        if(params.size() > 1) {
            // throw exception
        }
        if (params.get("title") != null) {
            return offerRepo.findByQuery("Offer_find_by_title", params.get("title"));
        }
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if more than 1 RequestParam is given in the request?

Why not with a fast fail check by relying on the count of non null parameters ?

```
public List<Offer> getOffers(@RequestParam(required = false) String title,
                             @RequestParam(required = false) String status,
                             @RequestParam(required = false) Double bidValue) {

  long countNonNull = Stream.of(title, status, bidValue).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();

   if (countNonNull > 1){
        throw new  ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "expect not more than one parameter among : title, status, bidValue");
   }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, this also worked. But I went with the answer above because I thought it looked a little cleaner. Thanks for your answer anyway.